# Will sites built on Backbone.js be unusable on computers with Javascript disabled?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been researching `Backbone.js` for a while and am trying to wrap my mind around it. It seems that when running `Backbone.js` you have are essentially passing all (or, as much as you want) of your server interactions through the `Backbone.js` layer.

My question is this:
Doesn't that mean that if JavaScript was disabled, your application/site would no longer work? If so, is this considered not a big deal? What's best practice for serving a fall-back or notifying the user that they need to enable `Javascript`?

Comment: Easy enough to try. Go to a site built with `backbone.js` and disable javascript.

Comment: Good point. =P. For others wishing to give it a try, http://disqus.com/ is a great example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for all effects and purposes any single-page applications, whether built with Backbone or any other framework, require JavaScript to run.

It is possible to design a website which functions as a traditional, document/hyperlink -based application and then enhance it with javascript. This type of design is called progressive enhancement, and it severely breaks down with more complex applications. Backbone, for one, expects you do fetch data from RESTful services and display it using client-side rendering. To support users without JavaScript, you would essentially have to build two different sites.

You need to evaluate whether the javascript disabled browsers are a significant part of your user base. If they are, you shouldn't build a Backbone application. What's your use case? If you're creating a website for an advertisement campaign where 100% accessibility and SEO are important, you should probably stick to server-side rendering. If you're creating a complex and ambitious web application, you should expect your users to be able to run JavaScript.

In any case you should use the `<noscript>` tag to inform the user to enable JavaScript in their browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a website built on a javascript library will not work with javascript disabled